# react-leaflet: adding a TopoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, topojson, react-leaflet

I just started using the react-leaflet library and got a map to load with a geoJSON layer, however I would like to use a TopoJSON layer instead.

I know that it is possible with pure Leaflet like this: https://gist.github.com/rclark/5779673/.

But how would I go about doing this with React-Leaflet?

**Edit**

```
class MapViz extends React.Component {

    getStyle() {...};

    render() {
        const position = [x,y];
        var geoData = topojson.feature(test_topo,test_topo.objects).geometries;
        return (
            <Map id="my-map" center={position} zoom={10.2}>
                <TileLayer ... />
                <GeoJSON data={geoData} style={this.getStyle} />
            </Map>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [provided TopoJSON layer](https://gist.github.com/rclark/5779673/) the following component for rendering TopoJSON could be introduced for `react-leaflet` library

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { GeoJSON, withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import * as topojson from "topojson-client";

function TopoJSON(props) {
  const layerRef = useRef(null);
  const { data, ...defProps } = props;

  function addData(layer, jsonData) {
    if (jsonData.type === "Topology") {
      for (let key in jsonData.objects) {
        let geojson = topojson.feature(jsonData, jsonData.objects[key]);
        layer.addData(geojson);
      }
    } else {
      layer.addData(jsonData);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const layer = layerRef.current.leafletElement;
    addData(layer, props.data);
  }, []);

  return <GeoJSON ref={layerRef} {...defProps} />;
}

export default withLeaflet(TopoJSON);
```

Notes:

- it extends [`GeoJSON` component](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components#geojson) from `react-leaflet` library
- there is a dependency to [`topojson-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/topojson-client) which provides tools for manipulating TopoJSON

**Usage**

```
<Map center={[37.2756537,-104.6561154]} zoom={5}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
     <TopoJSON
      data={data}
      />
</Map>
```

**Result**

[image]

Here is a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nogiq8)

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to the gist you linked. You need to convert from TopoJSON to GeoJSON and set the data as usually you do with GeoJSON.
It can be in your render method

```
 import topojson from 'topojson';
 ....
 ....


render() {
  geoData = topojson.feature(topoData,topoData.objects).features;

  return (
    <LeafletMap>
      <GeoJson
        data={geoData}
      />
     </LeafletMap>
  ) 
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to show the code:
But this error appears:
```Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `data` is marked as required in `GeoJSON`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in GeoJSON (created by MapViz)
    in MapViz (created by App)```

Comment: your geoData is undefined, check if you properly loading the test_topo or getting the right properties of it