# React leaflet Canvas

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I am trying to draw about 50K points with the leaflet Marker method and it's impossible du the time rendering and ram needed.
The new method I saw is to use Leaflet-canvas to draw point on-screen ' not in the DOM.
How can I perform this in React leaflet 3.X.
I tried
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-canvas-markers
But it doesn't support the V3 of the leaflet.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

install and import the library `npm i leaflet-canvas-marker`

Create a custom component and use a useEffect that will mimic the behavior of vanilla leaflet [example](https://ejuke.github.io/Leaflet.Canvas-Markers/examples/index.html)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet-canvas-marker";
import L from "leaflet";

export default function LeafletCanvasMarker() {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    var ciLayer = L.canvasIconLayer({}).addTo(map);

    ciLayer.addOnClickListener(function (e, data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    ciLayer.addOnHoverListener(function (e, data) {
      console.log(data[0].data._leaflet_id);
    });

    var icon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
      iconSize: [20, 18],
      iconAnchor: [10, 9],
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
      var marker = L.marker(
        [58.5578 + Math.random() * 1.8, 29.0087 + Math.random() * 3.6],
        { icon: icon }
      ).bindPopup("I Am " + i);
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    ciLayer.addLayers(markers);
  }, [map]);

  return null;
}
```

Include your custom component as a MapContainer child

```
<MapContainer center={position} zoom={10} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
   <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      />
   <LeafletCanvasMarker />
</MapContainer>
```

You should get a result similar to the following picture:
[image]